# Microsoft oauth2 authorization and admin permissions

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I'm upgrading an app that I have that currently uses the `https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize` endpoint and uses the `admin_consent` prompt.

I'm changing this to use the newer `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize` endpoint

Using the `admin_consent`, I get a full list of permissions that I need to accept, whilst when I pass some `scope` parameters to the new endpoint, I get the following checkbox:

[image]

I am currently passing in some `scope` permissions, notably `offline_access` as I need a refresh_token back from the oauth2 callback.

If I select he checkbox, is this the same as the `admin_consent` permission?

Also, is there a way for this to be automatic and not requiring consent?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, same as admin consent. No, consent requires user intervention.